# Your selves, yourselves or neither?

Tags: proper-nouns, compounds

When trying to substitute “*subconscious, conscious*” with the word “*selves*” in the following definition:

Meditation- the art of becoming one with your subconscious & conscious.

- ...become one with yourselves
- ...become one with yourselfs’
- ...become one with your-selves
- Or none of the above ::smh::

Also, is one capitalized?

My thought process: We want to show that we have ownership of our varying lvls of multiple states of  consciousness. Does the compound vs hyphenated vs no hyphen really make a big difference?

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is that "sub-conscious" has taken on a meaning as an independent noun whereas the adjective "conscious" has not. This breaks up the possibility of parallelism between nouns. "Sub-conscious," however, still exists as an adjective as well as a noun. Thinking that way leads naturally to

> your conscious and sub-conscious selves

or

> your conscious and sub-conscious thoughts

or

> your conscious and sub-concious desires

Once you treat both words as adjectives, you have tremendous opportunity for flexibility and variation in the associated nouns,